# How to override equals method in a non-attributes generic class?

Tags: java, generic-programming

I have a generic class that has no attributes, but a method with generic type. How can I override the equals method for it?

```
   public Foo<T> {
       boolean method(T bar){
           if (bar instanceOf Boolean) // do something and return 
           if (bar instanceOf String) // do something and return
           return false;
       }
   }
```

And intuitional `Foo<String> s` and `Foo<Boolean> b` should be different, so how can I override the equals to reflect this? Or it is bad to write a class like this?

Comment: What do you mean "no attributes?"  Does it have any fields at all?  Some sort of context for the use model for such an object would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like a potential XY problem.

Comment: Those `instanceof` lines are a definite code smell.  Sounds you want subclasses, like `class BooleanFoo extends Foo<Boolean>` and `class StringFoo extends Foo<String>`.  Or, pass a [Consumer<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html) to each Foo to use as a delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that if there are no attributes (which I take to mean `instance` fields), then the class should probably not be capable of being instantiated and the methods should be declared `static` (like the `Math class` in the Java API).  In any event I don't believe you would need to override equals since it doesn't seem likely you would compare multiple instances.  You could do your example method as follows:

```
    public static <T> boolean method(T foo) {
        if (foo instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("You passed a string");
            return true;
        } 
        if (foo instanceof Integer) {
            System.out.println("You passed an integer");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But if you really want to override equals, you could do something like this.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   return this == o;
}
```